# Problem generating burst mode PWM signal using pwm.h library with an Arduino

Tags: power-electronics

I am facing difficulties in generating a burst mode PWM signal using PWM.h library with an Arduino. I want to generate the following signals.

[image: The signals]

Can you please help me with my code?

Is there a better way to generate it?

````c
#include <PWM.h>

int32_t frequency_half = 10000; //frequency (in Hz)
int32_t frequency_buck = 60000;
int VG1 = 9;
int VG2 = 10;
float a;

void setup()
{
  InitTimersSafe();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("I am ready");
  bool success_1 = SetPinFrequencySafe(VG1, frequency_half);
  bool success_2 = SetPinFrequencySafe(VG2, frequency_buck);
  if (success_2) {
    pinMode (13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite (13, HIGH);

  }
}

void loop()
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  pwmWrite(VG1, sensorValue / 4);
  a = digitalRead(VG1);
  Serial.println(a);

  if (digitalRead(VG1) == HIGH)
  {

    pwmWrite(VG2, 64);
    delay(30);


  }
  delay (30);


}
```
````

Comment: Could you explain what the problem or difficulty is? What do you need help with? Are you sure this is more suitable in EE.SE than in Arduino.SE? How does it relate to power-electronics tag?

Comment: Do you have an external AND gate connected to pin 9 and 10 to create the burst signal?

Comment: @Justme Basically I need two pwm signal to drive two mosfets for a circuit .
1st signal will be a normal pwm signal with frequency,f1=(lets say 20khz) with D1=50% duty cycle.
2nd one will be  pulse skipped signal (burst mode) .That  means when the fiist signal is high ,2nd signal will be activated with frequency f2=(lets say 100khz),duty cycle D2=(lets say 40%)and when 1st signal is zero, 2nd signal will be zero.

I need to implement this with arduino or any other microcontroller .I am not allowed to use AND gate.

Comment: In my experience you either use the standard PWM library together with an external AND gate or you have to write your own code including interrupt handlers to enable and disable one PWM channel at the edges of the other channel.

Comment: @Jens could you please help me with that??

Answer (score 0):

The used hardware is not specified, so I will describe an abstract approach.

1. If your frequency f1 is 20 kHz with 50% duty cycle, you can setup a timer with 40 kHz interrupt rate.
2. You declare a volatile boolean variable, that will be toggled inside the timer interrupt handler.
3. If this variable is true you set output VG1 true and enable the PWM generator for frequency f2.
4. If this variable is false you disable the f2 PWM and set output VG2 to low and finally set output VG1 to low.

An interrupt rate of 40 kHz is possible on ATmega based Arduinos, but the CPU load is high and there is not much left for other calculations. On 32 bit MCUs this is not such a problem.

On some MCU implementations you can use a continous PWM for f2 and just toggle the pin mode of VG2 between output and input inside the interrupt handler to produce the bursts. However this toggle may hit the high frequency signal anywhere in the period and produces shorter pulses at the boundaries of the burst.

Another option is to connect the VG1 output directly to a 20 kHz PWM channel, but then you need two interrupt handlers, one for the rising edge and one for the falling edge, typically the are called compare interrupt and overflow interrupt. The toggle boolean is not required in this solution, but there will be a short period where the VG1 output is low (done by hardware) until the higher frequency PWM is turned off (done by software int the int handler). I don't know if this will be a problem in your application.